# nginx directive execution phase

Tags: nginx

Nginx executes directives in different phases.

For example, **set** in rewrite phase, **proxy_pass** in content phase.

How can I check in which phase a directive or a ngx_module is executed.

It seems there is no information about it on Nginx document. Anyone knows it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will need to look in the source code for the specific module. Why not ask about a specific directive of a specific module and perhaps someone might be able to help.